# how can i receive the body of an axios post request with express nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, post, axios

my browser side js code:

```
import axios from 'axios';

var testObject = {
   field : 'this is a test field'
}

axios.post('/create', testObject)
.then((res) => {
   console.log(res);
});
```

my nodejs code:

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();

//middlewares
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist')));

app.post('/create', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  res.send('this is the server response');
});

const port = 3000;
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('server listening on port ' + port);
});
```

my node js output:

```
server listening on port 3000
{}
```

my browser console output:

```
{data: "this is the server response", status: 200, statusText: "OK", headers: {…}, config: 
{…}, …}
```

please look that I'm alredy using a parser body middleware, the request is working fine but for some reason the server cant get the request body.

Comment: Add `app.use(express.json());` too.

Comment: You have to use `app.use(express.json())` Check the answer for more details,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `app.use(express.json())`

```
// parse application/json
server.use(express.json());

app.post('/create', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  res.send('this is the server response');
});
```

You also have to update your ajax request with following:

```
contentType: "application/json",
data: JSON.stringify(hellodata),
```

Comment: No need to install `body-parser`, it's included with `express` package. just use `app.use(express.json())`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to use body-parser for Express. In case, your project depends on some generated boilerplate code, it's most likely already included in your main server script. If not:

`var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());`

`npm install body-parser --save`

now get `body` of your request in nodejs

`app.post('/create', (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req.body);
});`